# Combine MYSQL & Postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have two different sites in my Intranet.. 1st site Database is MYSQL, & second one is in Postgresql. how can I combine both database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't on a database level.

You can however use some language which has drivers for both and 'combine' them on a application level.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use [fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) (in PostgreSQL 9.1) to comunicate both databases, and an [example of this](http://pgsnake.blogspot.com/2011/08/postgresql-91-meet-mysql.html). However, for now, has some limitations.